# Is there any way to upload photos directly to picasa web albums without server side language?

Tags: javascript, html, picasa

I tried with php, but It's too slow because It uploads twice for a image (user -> my server -> picasa).

Is there any api or something to upload directly to picasa without server?

Answer (score 0):

No, [the API requires specific HTTP headers that cannot be mimicked from the browser](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostPhotos), and also [needs OAuth headers](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth).